# Not able to run mysql as admin in xampp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am unable to run mysql as admin.

In the xampp command window, I tried login in as root it was successful but not able to run MySQL as admin.

Even in the control panel, there are no such errors displayed everything seemed perfect but while running MySQL as admin it is showing invalid settings

Comment: In mysql, the one with full administrative right is known as "root".  In my understanding there is no user in mysql known as "admin"　(unless you create one)

Comment: I am talking about in xampp control panel  when u run something as admin..

Comment: Edit: When u run soemthing as admin it opens the localhost server right! That page is showing invalid settings.. In the control panel window there are no errors showing. [mysql]  Attempting to start MySQL app...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     [mysql]  Status change detected: running ..

Comment: In the control panel everything looking good except from the localhost server when I am starting mysql

Answer (score 0):

Did you install and run phpmyadmin ? (if you can run phpmyadmin, then login as root and your password and you can do all administrative works such as creating user / database, etc.)

In my understanding XAMPP comes with phpmyadmin by default. you may use the following standard link:

http://localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: I am not able to run it. I dont know why. What is the problem here?  I have manually changed 
in config.inc.php -  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false instead of true. But still the http://localhost/phpmyadmin doesnt wrk

Answer (score 0):

my config.inc.php was

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

I changed it to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

And this resolves my issue